# Row to column conversion in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

table Name : Addresses

```
AddressId  |  Name  |  AddressType  |   AddressDetails
--------------------------------------------------------
   1           A        Present              abcd
   2           A        Permanent            efgh
   3           A        Mailing              ijkl
   4           B        Present              mnop
   5           B        Permanent            qrst
   6           B        Mailing              uvwx
```

I want to make it such like below-

```
Name  |  Present  |   Permanent  | Mailing
-------------------------------------------
A        abcd           efgh       ijkl
B        mnop           qrst       uvwx
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? note: asking for "*help as soon as possible*" probably won't get you help any sooner - people rarely ask questions and don't consider getting an answer urgent.

Comment: you'll probably have to clarify your question along with adding a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select  Name, Present, Permanent, Mailing
from
(
  select Name,AddressType,AddressDetails
  from Address
) d
pivot
(
  for columnname in (Name, Present, Permanent, Mailing)
) piv;
```